# Insulation in the attic : choice between fire retardant and allergenic

Tags: insulation, attic

This is for a house in Portugal, where most houses have no insulation. I want to insulate the house (it is quite cold in the winter).
The plan is to lay down some isolation material on the floor of the attic. The attic is completely isolated from the rest of the house. The only way to get to it is from the roof. The floor is very thick concrete (80 cm of concrete).

The range of insulation product is fairly limited, because very few people isolate their house in Portugal. I basically have the following choices:

- glass wool
- rock wool
- synthetic material consisting of several layers of aluminium, polyester and polyethylene

Glass wool is out because rock wool appears superior in all respects.
Rock wool is great because it is fire retardant, but I worry that it might cause allergies to people living in the house (I am not worried about the allergy during installation, only for the people using the house).
The synthetic material seems great, but it is very flammable. Insulation quality is not a criterion because it is comparable.

So I basically have to decide on allergy versus fire retardant properties.

Given the very thick slab of concrete, is it reasonable to not worry about the flammable properties of the synthetic product? Maybe I can consider that the concrete will be protection enough? (it is a country where fires are common, due to high temperatures).

For allergies with rock wool, can anyone speak to that risk? Does the fact that the attic is completely closed from the rest of the house, with no window prevent the risk of allergy?

Comment: why are you worried about allergies?   Is the attic not sectioned off from your house?   In the US we would normally not be up in an attic without a mask on and would generally be doing work.   I mean some people do have storage there, if that is your case its a big part of your question.

Comment: I don't understand disregarding fiberglass because there's something better. It's the most commonly installed attic insulation in my northern climate (to R-50 or better).

Comment: I suggest limiting your question to that of allergens escaping the attic. "Speaking to risk" is a subjective discussion and not suited for DIYSE.

Comment: @DMoore my worry is that even though it is sectioned off, it could leak from the tile and come back down.

Comment: @isherwood I meant to say that between glass wool and rock wool, I would choose rock wool because it seems better, and the cost difference is not significant. So in my particular case, I have excluded glass wool.

Comment: You need to give us a tile picture that your attic can leak from.   That seems a big issue to me.

Comment: @DMoore I meant to say that it's a normal, traditional tiled roof. So there are always a bit of gap. I worry that maybe some particles from the rock wool could escape from the tile and get down over time. Not sure if my worry is overblown though.

Comment: You are worried that insulation will leave your attic and fall outside?   What would that do?

Comment: Sorry, I am not very clear. My worry is that rockwool releases small particules into the air. These particules could escape the attic (I think mainly via the tiles), and then come down in the garden and eventually in the house. I worry this could cause allergies to people living in the house.

Comment: Doesn't affect my answer, but are you sure about 80 cm? That is 31 inches - we're talking bomb shelter or bank vault thickness. And [an online calculator](https://www.dumpsters.com/resources/concrete-weight-calculator) says that a 200 square foot (which would be a pretty small house) 80 cm thick concrete slab would weigh 19.5 tons! That is a **lot**. Maybe 8 cm?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, no. I know for sure the walls are 80 cm thick, and I assumed the floor therefore would be as thick. Is that an incorrect inference ?

Comment: You've got a good answer, but my question for you is why are you worried about an allergic response to _any_ of the insulation materials you are considering? Are any of these materials known to cause allergic reactions? Are any of the residents known to be highly allergic to a wide variety of materials? Until you're fairly confident that allergic reactions are going to be an issue for you/your family/tenants, don't worry about it in _any_ of the materials you're considering for any around-the-house projects.

Comment: I have no strong reason to be worried about allergies. I had the impression that this type of material could be allergenic. I guess I am trying to be cautious, and want to ask questions before doing the work. It seems from the answer and your comment that there is no real need to worry about the allergy, but it seems reasonable to worry about the fire risk. I think I'll go with the rock wool then.

Comment: @FreeMan There is a **lot** of misinformation, partial information, urban myths, etc. out there about so many things. Has been for a long time - the internet has only accelerated it. I think it is to the credit of the OP that they asked specific questions in a reasonably reliable site rather than relying on hearsay. I'm sure they're not the only one out there unclear about the difference between *allergies* and *irritants* and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR Don't worry, be happy, use the rock wool.

I am **NOT** an expert on insulation, so if anyone has better/more complete information, I will defer to them.

As a **general** rule, allergies have to do with specific organic materials - e.g., pollen - that cause an actual *allergic reaction*. This is a specific medical term and, as I understand it, allergies are not normally to minerals, synthetic fibers, etc. In other words, I doubt (but I could be wrong) that rock wool can actually cause an allergic reaction.

On the other hand, there are other types of *irritants* which can cause rashes (contact dermatitis), lung problems (asbestos being the classic example) and other symptoms, many of them quite serious, that are *similar* to allergies in certain respects. But they are not allergies.

My gut feeling is that none of these 3 choices (fiberglass, rock wool, synthetic insulation) will cause a true allergy, with the possible exception of outgassing of some chemicals used in production of the material. Such outgassing would be, in my opinion, a total non-issue for residents of a building if the materials are installed in a non-accessed attic. Any outgassing would escape through attic vents and dissipate into the atmosphere at very low levels.

Similarly, any particulate matter that comes out from any of these materials would be essentially indistinguishable from ordinary dust and other particles in the air from a variety of sources - soil, automobile exhaust, fireplaces, etc. In addition, properly installed insulation should have almost no loose particulate matter except as part of the initial installation. That initial installation should include cleanup of any loose particles (e.g., with a shop vacuum). The only exception would be if you used loose-fill (e.g., blown in) insulation, which would not be a good idea with these concerns, and in fact is probably best left to totally concealed spaces such as post-construction fill in external walls.

Fire is an issue. Attics get hot. Sometimes **very hot**. If (I haven't checked the specs) rock wool is significantly more fire retardant than other materials, use the rock wool. While the concrete should provide a lot of protection - hopefully enough for everyone to exit the building safely in the event of an attic fire - there could still be extensive (and expensive) damage. Best to avoid adding fuel to the fire.

*But probably every one of these items has a [Prop. 65 warning](https://www.p65warnings.ca.gov/).*

Comment: _According to the State of California, **everything** is bad for you, so please stop eating, drinking, and breathing - they'll all kill you_

Comment: Lol, probably true. Life is a lethal sexually transmitted disease after all. Terrible idea to perpetuate it.